# Changing Placeholder Text On Focus

Tags: jquery, html, input, placeholder

Is there a simple solution for changing placeholder text when an input is in focus? For example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Join our mailing list!">
```

would become this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your email address...">
```

while the input is active.

Comment: Keep in mind IE9 and below don't support `placeholder` and some browsers clear the text when the input gets focus.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'enter your email address...')
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Join our mailing list!')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ByLGs/

- [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)
- [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Comment: how to revert back first placeholder after the user clicks somewhere else ?

Comment: @Muli You need to add a `blur` handler, just like the above code snippet!

Comment: Answer added to go back function, whitout using title attr. Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You have this tagged "jQuery" so I assume you're open to using it. Here's a simple way:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Join our mailing list!" title="enter your email address...">​
```

```
$('input').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder')); // Store for blur
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).attr('title'));
}).on('blur', function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m6j8m/

This could be shortened up, but you get the idea. This way you don't have to keep track of attribute values in your javascript, it's all in the HTML so it's a one-size-fits-all solution. If using `title` doesn't suit your needs, you can use `data-` attributes instead or some other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom attributes "data", to swap content:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Join our mailing list!" data-focus-placeholder="enter your email address..." class="focus-placeholder">​
```

Then, you need a JavaScript function to swap attributes on focus and focusout

```
jQuery('.focus-placeholder').on('focus focusout',function(){

    focusPlaceholder    = jQuery(this).attr('data-focus-placeholder');
    placeholder         = jQuery(this).attr('placeholder');

    jQuery(this).attr('placeholder', focusPlaceholder);
    jQuery(this).attr('data-focus-placeholder', placeholder);
});
```

More bout DATA attributes: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp